# Is there a way to rewrite this function to be total?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have a function, shown below, which someone on Code Review suggested I rewrite to be total. They suggested that the calls to `getRow` and `(!)` could be replaced with calls to `zip` or `fold`.

I've thought about this and I can't really see how to rewrite it that way, nor do I have a good sense of how I would teach myself how to rewrite it.

```hs
import Data.Matrix (Matrix, getRow, ncols)
import Data.Vector ((!))

type AdjacencyMatrix = Matrix Bool

-- Input: the graph's adjacency matrix and a vertex. 
-- Output: the list of neighbours of that vertex.
neighbours :: AdjacencyMatrix -> Int -> [Int]
neighbours mat n = filter (\m -> row ! m) [0..(ncols mat)-1]
        where row = getRow n mat
```

This code snippet works within the context of my program, but if `n` is larger than `(ncols mat) - 1` then some of the `row ! m` calls will fail.

Comment: You can use `safeGetRow :: Matrix a -> Maybe (Vector a)`. Qustion is what you want to do in case the `n` is "out of range".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of [**`safeGetRow :: Matrix a -> Maybe (Vector a)`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/matrix-0.3.6.1/docs/Data-Matrix.html#v:safeGetRow) that will return a `Nothing` in case the index is out of range.

The question is of course what we do in case the index is out of range. Two reasonable options are:

1. use `Maybe [Int]` instead of `[Int]` as return type and return a `Nothing`; or
2. return an empty list, since if the node is not in the adjacency matrix, it has no neignbors.

We can for example implement this as:

```
import Data.Matrix(Matrix, safeGetRow)
import Data.Vector(toList)

neighbours :: AdjacencyMatrix -> Int -> Maybe [Int]
neighbours mat n = map fst . filter snd . zip [0..] . toList <$> safeGetRow n mat
```

We here make use of [**`toList :: Vector a -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.1/docs/Data-Vector.html#v:toList) to prevent using [**`(!) :: Vector a -> Int -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.1/docs/Data-Vector.html#v:-33-) which *looks* unsafe: you used correc indices, but this requires some reasoning, whereas `toList` is a total function, and thus clearly will always produce a result.

We can make this more compact by using [**`findIndices :: (a -> Bool) -> Vector a -> Vector Int`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.12.0.1/docs/Data-Vector.html#v:findIndices):

```
import Data.Matrix(Matrix, safeGetRow)
import Data.Vector(findIndices, toList)

neighbours :: AdjacencyMatrix -> Int -> Maybe [Int]
neighbours mat n = toList . findIndices id <$> safeGetRow n mat
```

Or we can use [**`maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:maybe) to use an empty list instead:

```
import Data.Matrix(Matrix, safeGetRow)
import Data.Maybe(maybe)
import Data.Vector(findIndices, toList)

neighbours :: AdjacencyMatrix -> Int -> [Int]
neighbours mat n = maybe [] (toList . findIndices id) (safeGetRow n mat)
```

Comment: Which option would you decide? What factors would you weigh in making this kind of decision in other contexts? I think I'm in favour of the "return an empty list" idea here, but I'm curious how this would be done in other contexts.

Comment: @lachrimae: personally I would use the one with a `Maybe`, since then the result has extra data: there is after all a difference between an "index out of range", and a row without `True`s, but that of course is more "personal taste".

Comment: This is a moment where [liquid haskell](https://ucsd-progsys.github.io/liquidhaskell-blog/) could be quite nice also, since if the program is correctly written you should never hit an out of range condition, so it's more like a compile time invariant. You would have to do some work to get Matrix into its brain though, I think. @lachrimae

Comment: Have Haskellers adopted Liquid Haskell as a "standard tool", or do they use it in specialized situations? It looks very cool, and I'm wondering whether this is something that should become core to my practices or not.